# How to create a custom template for individual markdown cells in JupyterLab

Tags: html, css, markdown, jupyter-lab

I to trying build a code for create customizable markdown cells in Jupyter notebook. I want to mean, create a some code in css and then call a method within a markdown cell for styling the cell.

I currently do the following in each Markdown cell that I want to personlize:

```
<font color=##FFFFFF>
    <em>
        <small>
Style 1
        <\small>   
    <em>
<\font>
```

or

```
<font color=#F9F60C>
    <b>
        <big>
Style 2
        <\big>   
    <\b>
<\font>
```

but I want some compact way of doing this by calling some predefined method in some CSS style sheet.

I do not have much knowledge in CSS and HTML and I have no idea if this is possible. I hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS for HTML tags. For example:

```html
<span style="color: white; background-color: OrangeRed; padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px; border-radius: 2px;">Example text</span>
```